# While launching Apache NetBeans terminal shows: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: apache2, netbeans, legal

I just want to know what do that means? Also, the terminal displays something is illegal, and I don't want do something against TOS, EULA or so.

Error message:

```
Gtk-Message: 23:29:35.404: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue (jar:file:/home/mada98/programs98/Apache%20Netbeans98/incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin/netbeans/platform/modules/org-netbeans-swing-plaf.jar!/) to method javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.getColorForState(javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthContext,javax.swing.plaf.synth.ColorType)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

The program however is working fine.

Comment: What was the command corresponding to the message you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For error related to `canberra-gtk-module`:

It's a a GtkModule which will automatically hook into all kinds of events inside a GTK+ program and generate sound events from them, i.e. it is responsible for generating sounds whenever a event, for example, error, happens. It can be easily installed using:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

#### Regarding `illegal` messages:

Not everything which mentions illegal is against TOS and EULA. Relax you are not doing any sort of illegal activity. Illegal in programming means that either you are not authorized to perform a specific activity or you've tried to perform an action in a way that it not intended, for example, [IllegalArgumentException](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-how-to-solve-illegal-argument-exception/).

These warnings seems to be related to swings caused by some jar files. You can ignore these warnings.